# Formula to get the coordinates of the intersection between a segment AB and a circle of radius R

Tags: geometry

Assume there is a circle of radius R where the center O is the origin.
Then two points A and B form a segment [AB].

What is the formula that gives the coordinates I (x_i, y_i) where I is the intersection between the segment AB and the circle. The formula is in terms of A (x_a, y_a)  , B (x_b, y_b) and R

(Assume A is always within the circle and B is always outside the circle )

[image: ate]

Comment: A is always assumed within the circle and B is always assumed outside the circle

Comment: Have you tried to find it? Get the equation of the line $AB$ in the form $y=mx+r$ (or $x=ny+s$. Substitute into the equation of the circle. Solve the quadratic. Then check which of the two roots is the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it.

The equation of the circle is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.

And equation of the line is $(y-y_a) = (x-x_a)\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}$.

Or $y = mx + b$ where $m=\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}$  and $b= y_a -x_am$.

$(x_i, y_i)$ satisfies both the equations so

$y_i = mx_i + b$

And $x_i^2 + y_i^2 = r^2$

......

So... just do it....

plug $y_i = mx_i + b$ into $x_i^2 + y_i^2 = r^2$ to get:

$x_i^2 + (mx_i + b)^2 = r^2$

.... and now just... do it... use the quadratic formula

$(m^2 + 1)x_i^2 + 2mbx_i + (b^2 -r^2) = 0$ and

$x_i = \frac {-2mb \pm\sqrt{4m^2b^2 - 4(b^2-r^2)(m^2+ 1)}}{2m^2+1}$

and $y_i = \frac {-2mb \pm\sqrt{4m^2b^2 - 4(b^2-r^2)(m^2+ 1)}}{2m^2+1}m + b$.

.... or..

$x_i = \frac {-2(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})(y_a -x_a(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})) \pm\sqrt{4(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})^2(y_a -x_a(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}))^2 - 4((y_a -x_a(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}))^2-r^2)((\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})^2+ 1)}}{2(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})^2+1}$

and $y_i = \frac {-2(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})(y_a -x_a(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}))b\pm \sqrt{4(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})^2(y_a -x_a(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}))^2 - 4(b^2-r^2)((\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})^2+ 1)}}{2(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a})^2+1}(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}) + (y_a -x_a(\frac {y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}))$.

---

Okay, I was tongue in cheek when I wrote that pointles equation but if we go back to $m$ and $b$ and simplify:

$x_i = \frac {-2mb \pm\sqrt{4m^2b^2 - 4(b^2-r^2)(m^2+ 1)}}{2m^2+1}=$

$\frac {-2mb \pm\sqrt{4m^2b^2 - 4b^2m^2+4m^2r^2-4m^2+4r^2}}{2m^2+1}=$

$\frac {-2mb \pm 2mr\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)}}{2m^2+1}=$

$\frac {-b \pm r\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)}}{m+\frac 1{2m}}=$

And $y_i = \frac {-b \pm r\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)}}{m+\frac 1{2m}}m + b=$

$\frac {-b \pm r\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)}}{1+\frac 1{2m^2}} + b=$

$\frac {-b \pm r\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)} +b(1+\frac 1{2m^2})}{1+\frac 1{2m^2}} =$

$\frac { \pm r\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)} +\frac b{2m^2}}{1+\frac 1{2m^2}} =$

$\frac { \frac b{2m}\pm mr\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)} }{m+\frac 1{2m}} =$

So $(x_i, y_i) = (\frac {-b \pm r\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)}}{m+\frac 1{2m}},  \frac {\frac b{2m}\pm mr\sqrt{1+(\frac 1m-\frac 1r)(\frac 1m+\frac 1r)} }{m+\frac 1{2m}})$

Which *is* a formula of sorts but... really, It's easier to just solve it than derive a formula.

....

For example if $r = 5$ and $A = (2,3)$ and $B=(6,4)$ then

The formula for the line is $y-3 = \frac {1}{4}(x-2)$ or $y=\frac 14x + \frac 72$.

So $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ and so $x^2 +(\frac 14x + \frac 72)^2 = 25$ and

$\frac {17}{16}x^2 + \frac 74x + \frac {49}{4} - 25=0$ or

$17x^2 + 28x + 4*19- 400=0$ or

$x =\frac {-28\pm{\sqrt{28^2 + 4*324}}}{2*34}=$

$\frac {-7\pm \frac 12\sqrt{49+324}}{17}=$

$\frac {-7\pm \frac 12\sqrt{373}}{17}$

And $y = \frac {-7\pm \frac 12\sqrt{373}}{68}+\frac 72=\frac {-237\pm \frac 12\sqrt{373}}{68}$.

Comment: I gagged. Still, +1

Comment: It's worth gagging over.  That's what the OP gets for asking for a "formula" rather than a far more simple "method of solving"

Answer (score 0):

A direct formula would be way too big and messy. Instead, know how to find it in steps.

You may use point-slope form of line to find the equation of the line.
$${{y-y_1}\over x-x_1} = m$$
$${{y-y_a}\over x-x_a} = {{y_a-y_b}\over {x_a-x_b}}$$
Equation of circle will be $x^2+y^2=R^2$

Substitute the value of x or y from the line equation in the circle equation and solve the quadratic to get $(x_i, y_i)$. The positions of the points don't matter as if there is no point of intersection, you will get imaginary values of x and y.